# Is there a way to change the ctrl+k shortcut in IE8 to focus on the search box in the top right corner (just like Firefox)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-8

I would like to change the shortcut in ie8 to map to search instead of copy tab. any ideas?

Comment: My best answer is... don't use ie8 (or 7, or 6, or 5..)

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+E works in IE8, but there's no way to remap it within IE.

If you really want Ctrl+K to jump to the search box, you could try using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or some similar program, which will let you remap keys for specific applications.